# Can I restrict my app sharedprefs data to google drive/cloud in android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-backup-service

I want to restrict my app's privacy data when user backup/restore in other device. Can I set **android:allowBackup="false"** in manifest file to achieve this?

I am saving unique Id in sharedprefs with uuid.randomstring(). So if user takes backup and restore on other device he should generate unique value. So, I have to restrict sharedprefs value when user enables google sync. To achieve that Can I use **android:allowBackup="false"**

Answer (score 0):

You can set `android:allowBackup="false"` to completely disable backup of your app or you can just specify:

```
<full-backup-content>
    <exclude domain="sharedpref" path="MYUNIQUEIDFILE.xml"/>
</full-backup-content>
```

to disable backup of the shared preference file where your id is set (see the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#IncludingFiles)). This also means that if user uninstalls and reinstalls your app in the same device new id will be generated. Or if user clears the data area of the app.

I think ideal solution would be to allow restoration of the backup only to a device where it was taken from, but I don't think that there is defined way to do that. And I have not been able to come up with good solution for that yet.